# How do you remap a key to the Caps Lock key in Xubuntu?

Tags: xubuntu

I'm using Xubuntu 12.04. How do I either swap or remap the <kbd>Control</kbd> (or any key) and <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> keys?

Answer (score 104, accepted):

Another way:

```
sudo vi /etc/default/keyboard
```

then find the line that starts with `XKBOPTIONS`, and add `ctrl:nocaps` to make Caps Lock an additional Control key or `ctrl:swapcaps` to swap Caps Lock and Control.

For example, mine looks like

```
XKBOPTIONS="lv3:ralt_alt,compose:menu,ctrl:nocaps"
```

then run

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
```

The reason this way is better is that it will take effect on the virtual consoles (e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>) as well as in the graphical desktop.

Comment: This is beautiful; how long has XKBOPTIONS been around for?

Comment: XkbOptions is named for a setting in X.  The capability is provided by the `console-setup` package, which seems to have been in Ubuntu since at least [Lucid](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/console-setup), and probably earlier.

Comment: I like your method, but unfortunately it just isn't working. I even see a new init image generated.

Comment: Works perfectly on xubuntu 14.04, thank you

Comment: Also works flawlessly here on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Is it possible that I have to fire the last command each time I start the desktop (LXDE in my case)?

Comment: Dror, yes, it's possible on some systems.

Comment: use `caps:escape` to remap the capslock to esc

Comment: I like that this works in the virtual consoles, but is there a way to make it "persistent" so I don't have to do it on every boot?

Comment: As far as I recall, you also need to ensure you've turned on any "Use system keyboard layout" option, and/or disabled IBus.  See e.g. http://askubuntu.com/a/442415/1951

Comment: I've got Unity for testing some stuff, so can't remove Ibus. It has "use system keyboard layout" set, and I've tried `sudo dconf write /desktop/ibus/general/use-system-keyboard-layout true`, didn't help. Ended up just making an .Xmodmap.

Comment: This works for 14.04. I'm appalled that Linux doesn't just have a setting for this in this day an age.

Comment: Also works for Lubuntu 15.10. A couple of the other answers seem specific to Xubuntu.

Comment: In additions there's a full list of options stored in ` /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/xorg.lst` if you're on something like an Ubuntu.

Comment: This seems to work only in the X, but not virtual consoles, tested on Ubuntu 17.10.

Comment: Works in xfce ubuntu 18.04 LTS. Needs a reboot though to take effect.

Answer (score 26):

To swap the keys go:

**Xubuntu** → **Settings Manager** → **Session and Startup**

Then in the Sessions and Startup configurator go

**Application Autostart** (tab at the top) → **Add** (bottom button)

Now on the **Add Application** screen

- **Name**: Control and CapsLk swap
- **Description**: Swap the two keys
- **Command**: /usr/bin/setxkbmap -option "ctrl:swapcaps"

---

To remap Caps Lock to Control go:

Xubuntu → Settings Manager → Session and Startup

Then in the Sessions and Startup configurator go

Application Autostart (tab at the top) → Add (bottom button)

Now on the Add Application screen

```
Name: Remap CapsLk to Ctrl
Description: Remap the CapsLk key to Control
Command: /usr/bin/setxkbmap -option "ctrl:nocaps"
```

Comment: Wow, that is dramatically harder than it used to be

Comment: On my almost fresh Ubuntu 13.10 install, it works when manually executed but not from “Session and Startup”.

Comment: I no longer suggest this method use the other answer. http://askubuntu.com/a/223674/29097

Answer (score 3):

For compose instead of caps put `compose:caps` as the `-options` parameter.

Answer (score 2):

For Raring (at least):

Start "Keyboard layout" (from dash).

Press "Options..." to reach "Keyboard layout options" menu.

I chose "Ctrl key position" => "Caps lock as Ctrl". Your tastes may differ.

Comment: What is "dash"?  Surely not Unity (in Xubuntu), I hope.  This sounds a lot like the Gnome solution that is unavailable in Xubuntu.