# How to remap CapsLock key to Ctrl in Xubuntu

Tags: xubuntu, autostart

I'm trying to remap my <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> key to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/149971/how-do-you-swap-or-remap-control-and-caps-lock-keys-in-xubuntu) (adding `/usr/bin/setxkbmap -option "ctrl:nocaps"` command to "Session and Startup"->"Application Autostart").

But this doesn't work in Xubuntu 12.04.

When I'm running the same command (`/usr/bin/setxkbmap -option "ctrl:nocaps"`) from terminal everything works as expected. If I change command to: `sh -c "/usr/bin/setxkbmap -option \"ctrl:nocaps\""` it again works if I'm running it from terminal, but it doesn't work if I add it to xfce "Session and Startup" configurator. Also when I create a script like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/bin/setxkbmap -option "ctrl:nocaps"
```

and add it to startup via "Session and startup" configurator, it has no effect at all. But if I run this script after login it actually remaps caps key as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, my problem was because of `xfce4-xkb-plugin`. It was resetting xkb settings each time. I just installed `xxkb` instead of it, and now everything works absolutely fine!

Comment: Please mark your answer as accepted! That way the question is closed and people know the solution works :)