# Change search key to caps lock (Pixel)

Tags: 12.04, unity, chromebook

I seem to be the only one who actually uses caps lock on a regular basis.  I've found plenty of details on mapping caps lock to something else, but nothing on how to map a key *to* caps lock.

On the Chromebook Pixel, the search key opens up Ubuntu Home.  How can I map that to caps lock?  The search key seems to be mapped to `Super`.

I've tried `/usr/bin/setxkbmap -option "super:caps"` according to a modified version of [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/301216/66075) but no results.

Comment: Does this help? http://askubuntu.com/questions/254424/how-can-i-change-what-keys-on-my-keyboard-do-how-can-i-create-custom-keyboard/300203#300203

Comment: That collection of answers did finally lead me to the solution below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding the following to `~/.Xmodmap` fixed this:

```
keysym Super_L = Caps_Lock
```