# Different keyboard mapping after installing nvidia-prime

Tags: nvidia, keyboard, themes, gtk, nvidia-prime

After installing nvidia-319, nvidia-settings-319 and nvidia-prime, my keyboard mapping is different. When I press the hyphen key, it enters a forward slash. And that's just one example. And it also changed my GTK theme to the old Windows 98 thing. I don't have a particular problem with the theming, but the keyboard mapping annoys me greatly. Is there a fix for this, or am I just completely out?

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same problem after installing nvidia-prime. I found a solution here:

**[Keyboard layout switches to English each time I reboot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/362973/language-problem-in-ubuntu-13-10)**

and applied:

```
setxkbmap de
```

where "de" denotes "German" keyboard layout. Hope this helps!