# Keyboard keeps defaulting to wrong layout

Tags: 14.04, keyboard, keyboard-layout

Each time I reboot the keyboard re-sets so that the keys for @ and " are reversed; # appears where the UK pound symbol should be, etc.

I have tried lots of fixes posted here and on other forums, and most of them work temporarily, but not after a reboot. It would help me, and doubtless many other users in future, if someone could post a step-by-step guide to diagnosing and solving the problem.

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 with a full-size Dell UK keyboard; let me know what system info you need.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the contents of the /etc/default/keyboard file ?

Comment: It was (and still is, after applying the fix below):
XKBMODEL="pc105"

XKBLAYOUT="gb"

XKBVARIANT=""

XKBOPTIONS=""

Comment: See also http://askubuntu.com/questions/362973/keyboard-layout-switches-to-english-each-time-i-reboot

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had a similar issue and solved it by doing two things.

## 1. Dconf Editor

Install dconf-tools and open it.
Under desktop/ibus/general find engines order and change it to your preference.

## ibus-setup

open a terminal and type ibus-setup
Under the advanced tab tick the **use system keyboard layout** option.

Comment: This worked for me on ubuntu 14.04 except that I installed and used dconf-editor, as dconf-tools wasn't available. I also rebooted my laptop for it to take effect.