# @ symbol and " swapped on keyboard

Tags: 14.04, keyboard, keyboard-layout, dconf

I've very recently installed Ubuntu 14.04 (on a Dell Latitude 640M with XP Professional in a separate partition) and the two symbols @ and " have swapped positions on the keyboard (I chose UK language setup). I have a full size separate Logitech keyboard, and the swapped key fault also occurs on my laptop keyboard.

I tried two fixes suggested in another [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/467733/keyboard-keeps-defaulting-to-wrong-layout): ibus-setup and dconf tool. Ticking the recommended box in the ibus setup didn't have any effect. When I opened the dconf Editor it didn't seem to work as no options come up when I click on any menu items. I tried reinstalling (using Synaptic Device manager) but no change.

Thanks for any help. Finding my way around Ubuntu is a steep learning curve.

Comment: Have you tried to play with a keyboard model in system settings? I.e. I have there a `Generic | standart PC 101 keys`. Sorry that I can't tell you an exact option, I just have KDE, not Gnome; but I am sure that the Gnome probably have alike option.

Comment: I just checked in System Settings and there is no mention of keyboard model, only options about repeat keys and shortcuts. Thanks

Comment: Okay, I have another idea(but please, bear in mind that I have not Gnome): in the window where you can add new keyboard layout is many variants for the same language. I.e. the English one have *English Gana, English USA*, and something about ten layouts more. Try to look there.

Comment: You may find this useful: [How do I remap certain keys](http://askubuntu.com/q/24916/295286)

Comment: Thank you all, I've since solved the problem but don't remember how I did it - it may have been by changing to a different keyboard option, as someone has since suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem - I removed US keyboard as an option even though UK was chosen first in list, just leaving the UK keyboard, and it reverted back to how it should be. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

i had same problem in raspbian linux distribution.
i Changed keyboard setting
 Model : 104 key model (Which i was using)
 Layout: Indian
 Variant: Indian with rupee sign.
I worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone still having a problem after trying all these please follow the following things.
first go to settings, then Region and Language in that go to input source add English US keyboard layout by pressing + symbol and remove other keyboard layout by pressing - symbol.
thank you

Answer (score -1):

Try to change the Language to English(US) using the **En** indicator on the top bar. This indicator may show different letters based on the Language selected, For example **RU** for Russian etc.

Comment: The top of what?

Comment: That "En button on the top" is called keyboard indicator and it is located in the panel. What you can select there is also not the language but the keyboard layout.

Comment: @ByteCommander: Input source indicator nowadays, considering that also advanced input methods using e.g. IBus or Fcitx may be included in the input source menu. The options are also often referred to as input languages.