# Why does the 'r' command change keyboard layout to US? - Ubuntu GNOME

Tags: 14.04, gnome, keyboard-layout, locale, ubuntu-gnome

I have Ubuntu GNOME 14.04 installed on my machine with my system set to UK. When I run the `r` command via <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> to reset the shell, the keyboard layout changes to US even though my system's language, formats and input sources is set to UK. How do I prevent my system from going to US when I execute the 'r' command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the effect of these two bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-keyboard/+bug/1240198 and https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/1246272.

It is (still!) not fixed. There are a couple of workarounds: [Keyboard layout switches to English each time I reboot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/362973/keyboard-layout-switches-to-english-each-time-i-reboot) and [Keyboard keeps defaulting to wrong layout](https://askubuntu.com/questions/467733/keyboard-keeps-defaulting-to-wrong-layout) you can try.

Quoting the proposed workaround, from [Martin Jurča](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-keyboard/+bug/1240198/comments/19):

> 1. open terminal
> 2. run `ibus-setup`
> 3. open the *Advanced*  settings (the last tab)
> 4. check the "use system keyboard layout" checkbox

[image: Example of ibus-setup setting]

Comment: Thank you @Rmano [Comment 19](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-keyboard/+bug/1240198/comments/19) of [the first link](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-keyboard/+bug/1240198) fixed it for me.