# Texmaker accents problem

Tags: fonts, latex

I've installed Texmaker 4.1 (using apt) on Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS 64bits.
Most of the time it works fine, but out of the blue it starts to show some strange behavior with accents marks, for example, I type "á ã à" and get "´a ~a `a" and other strange things.

Some people seem to have solved this problem simply by installing ibus-qt4, but I've already tried that and the problem persists, I tried a lot of font encoding options too.

Strangely enough, the problem goes away for ~30min if I close and reopen Texmaker, but that is very annoying... any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Seems that your keyboard got resetted to US. Probably this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-gnome/+bug/1300435 (still unresolved and, sadly, mostly ignored)

Comment: @Rmano I don't think it's the same thing here, my problem happens only inside texmaker and I don't need to change the keyboard layout for it to fix, even though for a short time.

Comment: The fact that installing ibus-qt4 fixed this bug for some people and not for me is really strange...

Comment: Check this: http://askubuntu.com/a/467773/16395 it worked for some people. Although it could be another thing; I never used texmaker in Ubuntu.

Comment: @Rmano OK, I'll try it. I just have to keep working and wait for the problem to show up or not. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

solved the problem on Linux Mint by installing the **ibus** package.

Note that installing only **ibus-qt4** did not solve the problem.