# ibus override my xmodmap

Tags: ibus, xmodmap

I use xmodmap to swith Ctrl and Alt keys:

```
~ $> cat .Xmodmap
!
! based on: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SwapControlAltAndCapsLock#toc8
!

!----------------------------------------------------------
! Swap Control and Alt keys, both sides
!----------------------------------------------------------

! First clear all modifiers & control
clear control
clear mod1
clear mod4

! Swap Control_L and Alt_L
keycode  64 = Control_L
keycode  37 = Alt_L Meta_L

! Menu becomes Alt_R Meta_R (AltGr)
! keycode 135 = Alt_R Meta_R

! Define Control_R and Alt_R similar to Control_L and Alt_L
keycode 108 = Control_L
keycode 105 = Alt_L Meta_L

! We need to set keycodes first, as some programs (emacs!) read
! the key names and seem to ignore what's below.
add mod1    = Alt_L Alt_R Meta_L Meta_R
add mod4    = Super_L Super_R
add control = Control_L Control_R


!------------------------------------------
! Caps_Lock becomes an additional BackSpace
!------------------------------------------
! remove lock = Caps_Lock
! keysym Caps_Lock = BackSpaceclear control
! clear mod1
! keycode 37 = Alt_L Meta_L
! keycode 64 = Control_L
! keycode 105 = Alt_R Meta_R
! keycode 108 = Control_R
! add control = Control_L Control_R
! add mod1 = Alt_L Meta_L Alt_R Meta_R
```

That works fine; however, when I start ibus, the key mappings are overtaken by ibus. Is there a way to avoid this?

Answer (score 1):

Did you already try the following.

> ...try enabling the “Use system keyboard layout” option under the
>   “Advanced” tab in the IBus Preferences.

Hint from http://tots.1o24.org/how-to-stop-ibus-from-removing-your-xmodmap-mappings/

Comment: Yes. I've already done that. By the eway, I'm using Gnome shell. Maybe gnome shell is different with unity?

Comment: This one worked for me. Great!

Answer (score 1):

It's not exactly an IBus problem (IBus has problems, a lot(1), but I do not think this one).

Ubuntu, as any modern Linux, uses `xkb` extension to define the keyboard. `xmodmap` is sort-of legacy thing that is [not guaranteed to work with it](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/X_KeyBoard_extension#xmodmap).

The documentation is quite lacking. Arch Linux (as ever) [has a good page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/X_KeyBoard_extension). I have managed to [adapt my keyboard](http://rlog.rgtti.com/2014/05/01/how-to-modify-a-keyboard-layout-in-linux/) to avoid switching, which is plagued by bugs in Ubuntu Gnome(2).

The system is complex --- I found some help [here](http://madduck.net/docs/extending-xkb/), and [here](https://lists.debian.org/debian-x/2012/09/msg00274.html). But understanding how to change modifiers is still out of my set of skills... and I suspect very few people around understand it (scary).

---

*Footnotes:*

(1) [Keyboard keeps defaulting to wrong layout](https://askubuntu.com/questions/467733/keyboard-keeps-defaulting-to-wrong-layout), https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/1246272, much more...

(2) https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/1218322, https://bugs.launchpad.net/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/1244090

Comment: Thank you. The problem seems comlicated. Is there another way to remap key except xmodmap? That is, get ibus work first, and then remap ctrl and alt keys.

Comment: ...probably it's possible, but never tried it. Another link could be http://xkbconfig.livejournal.com/7996.html.

Comment: ...maybe this one: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/10008/52205 --- it's a bit of a hammer way, but may work. Or more cleanly here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65507/use-setxkbmap-to-swap-the-left-shift-and-left-control/65600#65600 (although seems that the second one conflicts with IBus, again. I hate IBus).

Answer (score 1):

- Actually, there is an ibus option hidden from its setup GUI to reload `.xmodmap` on method change.

  ```
  dconf write /desktop/ibus/general/use-xmodmap true
  ```

  I couldn't tried it yet, but you may check `/etc/dconf/db/ibus.d/00-upstream-settings` for available options.

  I'm using Xubuntu 16.04, it could be different than 14.04.
- Another way

  1. Stop ibus from using system keymaps

     ```
     dconf write /desktop/ibus/general/use-system-keyboard-layout false
     ```

     or using `ibus-setup`
  2. Change its own key mappings

     ```
     $ cat /usr/share/ibus/keymaps/modifiers 
     keycode 29 = Control_L
     keycode 42 = Shift_L
     keycode 54 = Shift_R
     keycode 56 = Alt_L
     keycode 97 = Control_R
     keycode 100 = Alt_R
     keycode 125 = Super_L
     keycode 126 = Super_R
     keycode 127 = Menu
     ```

     **Reference:** for configuration path

     > [ibus_keymap_get ()](https://ibus.github.io/docs/ibus-1.5/IBusKeymap.html#ibus-keymap-get)
     >
     > ```
     > IBusKeymap * ibus_keymap_get  (const gchar *name);
     >
     > Get an IBusKeymap associated with the giving name.
     >
     > This function loads the keymap file specified in name in
     >  the IBUS_DATA_DIR/keymaps directory.
     >
     > name :
     >   The keymap file to be loaded, such as 'us', 'jp'.
     >
     > Returns :
     >   An IBusKeymap associated with the giving name; or NULL if failed.
     > ```

Answer (score 0):

I've already faced this problem before and finally found out a solution for this by making a keyboard shortcut executing a command that has two jobs:

- Send <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> keystroke to system (this key combination will change the input source of IBUS)
- Load my xmodmap profile into system keymap

Take a look on my post for more detailed information about this solution:
http://blog.z1k.pw/?p=60

Comment: Does anyone have that blog.z1k.pw blog post cached. It's down, and not on archive.org.