# Use of leading # in password

Tags: password

On install I used a password #some1thing# (said it was strong)

Now it won't let me log in. So I used the guest account.

Open a terminal and echo #test produced a blank line. Echo t#est echoes OK.

I'm assuming my password has done the same. Do I have to re-install to fix this?

Comment: Passwords starting with `#` should be all right..check whether you are inputing it correctly..also in terminal you need `echo '#test'` or `echo \#test` ..this does not have anything to do with `shadow` file as the password is hashed so the `#` will not be present to make any mess in the `shadow` file..

Comment: Probably a layout problem. There is a Heisenbug jumping around. See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-keyboard/+bug/1240198 and http://askubuntu.com/questions/467733/keyboard-keeps-defaulting-to-wrong-layout .

Answer (score 1):

Your password is ok. Check the keyboard layout on login before you type your password.

Alternatively change your password:

1. Start the grub menu by holding the <kbd>LeftShift</kbd> key during the boot process.
2. Open the advanced options and start the recovery mode
3. Start the network via menu entry to remount the `/` writable (without an additionally command)
4. Start the root shell via the menu entry
5. Change your password via

   ```
   passwd <your_username>
   ```
6. Type `exit` and resume the boot process via menu entry