# Keyboard layout changes by itself

Tags: keyboard-layout

When Ubuntu is restarted, sometimes the keyboard layout is changed from Spanish to English. Does anyone know how to solve this problem? I've had it since Ubuntu 13.10.

Answer (score 0):

Just go into Settings=>Text entry=> and remove the English layout:

[image: Ubuntu Settings app]

[image: Text entry with the minus sign at the bottom selected]

That assumes you don't want the English layout at all. Given that your question was written in Spanish, I assume this is the case.

Comment: Not enough in Ubuntu 15 :-(

Comment: @procrastinator what do you mean not enough? Have you removed the English layout? And what happens? Do you still see the English? Where? For what user? Please post a new question explaining the issue.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. I did the manipulation but the keyboard layout kept changing. Here is something which worked for me (including the related comment): http://askubuntu.com/a/363585/392225.