# how to fix automatically keyboard layout (input method) change on start-up?

Tags: keyboard-layout, language-support

When starting computer, my default language (keyboard layout) is selected propertly. However, after few minutes the layout is changed to English (although Language Indicator is showing my language, not English). This happens on my two computers with Ubutnu 14.04. How to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and this post helped me. I am also using Ubuntu 14.04 and the answer of Steve B worked fine.

[Keyboardlayout Fix](https://askubuntu.com/questions/362973/keyboard-layout-switches-to-english-each-time-i-reboot)

It is not exactly the same but maybe it also helps with your problem.