# Swapping Caps Lock and Ctrl via udev

Tags: keyboard, udev

I want to swap `Caps Lock` and `Ctrl`. My solution so far is to edit `/etc/default/keyboard` and setting  `XKBOPTIONS="ctrl:nocaps"` There are problems with this solution. First it doesn't work with virtual consoles and it doesn't work with Source games. See https://github.com/ValveSoftware/Dota-2/issues/47

My keyboard is:

```
I: Bus=0011 Vendor=0001 Product=0001 Version=ab54
N: Name="AT Translated Set 2 keyboard"
P: Phys=isa0060/serio0/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input2
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=sysrq kbd event2 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=120013
B: KEY=402000000 3803078f800d001 feffffdfffefffff fffffffffffffffe
B: MSC=10
B: LED=7
```

I tried to follow this guide https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Map_scancodes_to_keycodes but it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about Source games, but this does work on virtual consoles for many of us.  See:  [How do you remap a key to the Caps Lock key in Xubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/149971/how-do-you-remap-a-key-to-the-caps-lock-key-in-xubuntu)

Comment: This is the solution I pointed out above. It's weird since I can Ctrl-Alt-F1(-F7) to a virtual console. Once there my CapsLock is CapsLock but I can still switch virtual consoles via CapsLock-Alt-FN.

Comment: Odd.  The /etc/default/keyboard approach works fine for me on Ubuntu trusty.