# Key swap not working after reboot

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

I am running 64 bit Ubuntu 14.04 and I want to swap my caps lock and control key. I run `setxkbmap -option ctrl:swapcaps` and it did work. But after reboot, it gets back to what it used to be: caps lock is caps lock, control is control. I have also tried using gnome-tweak-tool and the method here [How do you remap a key to the Caps Lock key in Xubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/149971/how-do-you-remap-a-key-to-the-caps-lock-key-in-xubuntu), but they are the same result: it works after running those commands but fails after reboot. How can I swap caps lock and control permanently, without losing it after reboot? Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the dconf-editor option setting described [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/66624/where-is-xkb-getting-its-configuration) ?

In your case you would leave the sources as is.
And change xkb-options to:

```
['ctrl:swapcaps']
```

[Should be a comment -- dont have 'reputation' for that :-) ]