# I want to run a script after the comupter wakes up from sleep state

Tags: keyboard, suspend, power-management

[How do I remap the caps lock key?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/53038/how-do-i-remap-the-caps-lock-key) teaches how to disable the CapsLock key. I have written a script which applies the command

```
setxkbmap -option caps:none
```

as part of an autostart procedure. It works fine, as long as I don't close the lid of my computer thus sending it to the suspend/sleep state (hibernation does not work with it).

Now I have found out that the `setxkbmap -option caps:none` is not restored after waking my computer up. I want to add such a command to a script which is automatically invoked when the computer wakes up again.

**Is this possible?**
**How and where do I have put this command?**

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/a/226284/77093

Comment: One has to place another script to (in my case) /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/99zzz_Wakeup.sh. See  https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Power_management#Sleep_hooks